# Perl reading in a file and getting a string in between two strings

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to read in a file and gather everything in between two hash keys. I want to access everything between the $beginString and $endString variables. I have tried multiple regular expressions but haven't been able to get one to work.

```
my $beginString = "SEARCH";
my $endString = "TEST";


my $fileContent;
open(my $fileHandler, $inputFile) or die "Could not open file '$inputFile' $!";
{
    local $/;
    $fileContent = <$fileHandler>;
}
close($fileHandler);



if($fileContent =~ /\b$beginString\b(.*?)\b$endString\b/){
    my $result = $1;
    print $result;
}

print Dumper($fileContent);
```

Comment: You need the `s`modifier if you want to span multiple lines `if($fileContent =~ /\b$beginString\b(.*?)\b$endString\b/s` `s` allows `dot' to match newlines.

Comment: Thank you! however it wasn't the full solution. What it did was return everything up to the $endString but i still got everything before the $beginString.

Comment: Tip: It's called a "file handle" (something that holds a resource), not a "file handler" (something that takes care of files).

Answer (score 0):

An adaptation of [the perl monks' solution](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=979946) could be..

```
my $beginString = "SEARCH";
my $endString = "TEST";

my $fileContent;
open(my $fileHandler, $inputFile) or die "Could not open file '$inputFile' $!";
while(<$fileHandler>) {
  if(/$beginString/../$endString/) {  $fileContent .= $_ unless(/$beginString/ or /$endString/) }
}
close($fileHandler);
print Dumper($fileContent);
```